# Elasticsearch - Deleting the previous versions of a document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a versioned index in Elasticsearch where I'm storing the document whenever a modification is made to it. After running it for some time I've realised that storing all the versions of a document is taking a lot of disk space.
I don't have any version field instead I use a date field in order to see the latest version and the one previous to it.

I just want to keep the last two versions. But I'm unable to figure out a way to delete the previous versions.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Periodically run a deletion of all documents ordered by date, from the latest to the oldest, starting from 2 ?

```
POST /INDEX/_delete_by_query?from=2&sort=DATE:desc
```

where INDEX is your index, and DATE the name of your date field.

Note: the 'from' parameter has been removed in Elasticsearch 8.x.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb, but do I need to add some logic to it, or running it would delete the records leaving the latest two versions of all the records?

Comment: And this is the error that I'm getting on running that command:
"reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;2: from is not supported in this context;3: query is missing;"

Comment: I've fixed my answer. The from parameter has been removed in Elasticsearch 8.x.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-delete-by-query.html

I don't have a simple solution in Elasticsearch 8.x

Comment: Do you know any way to delete the documents retrieved in inner_hits? I've been able to get the documents to be deleted in inner_hits but now I'm struggling to find a way to delete them.